# How to avoid multi threads working on a same task records without using lock?

Tags: multithreading, locking

I've a application, need to use windows service with multiple threads to read 100 task record from SQL server table or mongodb collection, once a thread finish to read the 100 task, it must to set the status from 0('not processing') to 50(means 'processing'), then the thread will do some business logic, once it's done, then update the status from 50 to 100(means 'DONE') OR -1(means 'error encountered'). My question is how to prevent several different threads to read the same 100 records from table if I choose not to use the lock?

Comment: There's no way to sensibly answer a question like this if you don't tell us why you don't want to use a lock. There's no way we can know if our answer meets your requirements if you don't tell us what they are. (Say someone wants to know how to get to work without using their car. Is "use someone else's car" a good answer? It might be perfect or it might totally miss the point. But without knowing what the point is, there's no way to know if that answers the question.)

Comment: One reason I didn't want to use the database lock is to avoid low performance, and I did heard someone told they will  use  a 'table' or something, and set a unique constraint on special column like a column named 'taskID' or something. Just wanner know more about this

Comment: See, I completely misunderstood your question. I thought you were talking about a mutex lock!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very simple. Just pick a reasonable number of records to process in a pass. Say you have 53,000 records and you choose 250 as the number to do per pass. That means you have 212 work units that need to be done and you can number them from 0 to 211 inclusive. Work unit `N` includes records `250*N` to `250*N+249` inclusive.

Now the problem reduces to giving each thread an undone work unit to do. So long as all work units are done and no two threads attempt to do the same work unit, no database locks are needed.

How you assign the work units to threads is language specific. But the simplest way is to use some kind of a thread pool and dispatch each work unit to that thread pool.